# Breakpoints broken when placed in VSCode/Javascript on Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, webpack, visual-studio-code

I'm running a node.js webapp using javascript and webpack which I built following [this guide](https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/). I've installed the chrome debugger extension.

I run the node server using the command:

```
webpack-dev-server --progress --colors
```

I've also run webpack --devtool source-map

My launch config looks like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

After running webpack-dev-server --progress --colors and hitting F5 in VSCode Chrome loads up with the webpage, all my breakpoints appear solid red but when placed they jump a bit lower from where I placed them (including on lines which are executing code). The breakpoints also don't hit which makes me believe there's something wrong with the debug mapping. When I have breakpoints placed on occasion random files get loaded and invisible breakpoints in them are hit, like in node_modules/firebase/index.js an invisible breakpoint over a commented out line is hit.

I should also note running .scripts in vscode does yield (amongst all the modules) my entry.js file which I'm trying to hit breakpoints in, namely: -webpack:///./entry.js (d:\myproject\entry.js)

Everything is placed in the root of my directories (screenshot in case I make a mistake transposing the directories);

[image]

Also my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: could you please show the root directory structure, such as where the bundled files are being placed?

Comment: @AjayGupta I just attached a pic of the root directory folder, let me know if that's what you wanted to see :)

Comment: So `Build` is where all the bundled assets go?

Comment: @AjayGupta oh no that's not the case, Build is a folder with Unity project files. Perhaps I don't quite understand how webpack works, is there a build directory that everything should be written to?

I thought the webpack file was built into my bundle.js file:

module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ]
    }
};

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't look closely for the bundle.js file.. Anyways, where exactly are you placing the breakpoints? for example on a line with just `{` or things like that?

Comment: Usually placing them on functions which should be executed like window.alert("test"), however after the breakpoint is pushed down by vscode they still don't get hit.

Comment: Please check out this link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5422

Comment: Moreover, you are placing you breakpoints in `bundle.js` right?

Comment: no I'm placing them in entry.js where my javascript functions are, I assumed vscode's chrome debugger would be smart enough to map them out correctly. I haven't had this issue debugging typescript projects for example.

Comment: No actually, as far as I know, its the `bundle.js` script that is running in the browser, so you should be placing your breakpoints in bundle.js. This happened to me when working on an AngularJS project. Try it and let me know, I'll post it as an answer :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Chrome debugger in vscode can map out bundle.js in chrome to your js file. If you've been debugging via bundle.js you should look into that, will save you a lot of hassle :)

Either way setting breakpoints in bundle.js didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem solved!

Needed to add:

```
 devtool: 'inline-source-map'
```

To my webpack.config.js module.exports. Now breakpoints hit inline on functions everywhere.